# API Callbacks onChangeSearchText - No data showing even there's a data

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-dropdown-picker

What I am trying here is to show the output of my search results

this is my reference for the search callback
https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/advanced/search#onchangesearchtext

This is my component

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import useContent2Store from '../../../store/useContent2Store';

const SearchBarMenu = ({}) => {

  const { ProductsStatus, fetchProducts } = useContent2Store((state) => state);

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  return (
    <View className="z-50 flex-row items-center rounded-lg px-2 pt-4 pb-2">
      <DropDownPicker
        open={open}
        value={value}
        items={items}
        setOpen={setOpen}
        setValue={setValue}
        categorySelectable={true}
        schema={{
          label: 'name',
          value: 'id',
          parent: 'context',
        }}
        loading={ProductsStatus?.loading}
        searchable={true}
        disableLocalSearch={true}
        searchPlaceholder="Search..."
        onChangeSearchText={(text) => {
          if (text && text?.length > 2) {
            fetchProducts({ searchTerm: text })
              .then((res) => {
                if (res.isSuccessful) {
                  setItems(res.searchResults)
                  console.log(res.searchResults)
                } else {
                  console.log(res.error)
                }
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
              })
          }
        }}
      />
    </View>
  )
};

export default SearchBarMenu;
```

This is the sample output from `res.searchResults`:

```json
[
  {
    "appImageUrl": "https://dummyimage.com/200x200/C1C1C1/C1C1C1.jpg",
    "context": "Category A",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "id": 29,
    "name": "Test 2",
    "price": 0,
    "tag": "Pages"
  },
  {
    "appImageUrl": "https://dummyimage.com/200x200/C1C1C1/C1C1C1.jpg",
    "context": "Category A",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "id": 32,
    "name": "Test 1",
    "price": 0,
    "tag": "Pages"
  },
  {
    "appImageUrl": null,
    "context": "Category B",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ",
    "id": 2330,
    "name": "Test 3",
    "price": 0,
    "tag": "Products"
  }
]
```

As you can see that I used schema and this is my reference:
https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/item-schema#customize-the-schema

Preview:

[image: Aug-09-2023 20-02-29]

Since I am already here asking, i would like to additionally add this question:

- is it possible instead of clicking the dropdown to search, why not just directly input then dropdown will show... if there's already option to that feature can you send me the right docs for that? If not, do you guys recommend other module for this one because I need a component that has input then it will show a dropdown when searched something that has group category support and image support.

---

[image]

Comment: The solution for this is creating my own module, But I will keep this open for others that have answer(s) for this one and for those dev looking for the same thing i was looking before.